# How to fix laravel error 5.8 Whoops! There was an error. when sharing on facebook?

Tags: laravel-5.8

When sharing my website link does not show the information generated by meta, I have already used Facebook debugger share and it shows me the same error, the meta tags are correctly indicated, but it always shows me that error when sharing.

Has anyone had this problem? Please help me.

[image: Demo Image]

Comment: If you visit that URL, is there actually an error?

Comment: no, the page is displayed normally  http://dral.regionlima.gob.pe/

Comment: I get a server error. Perhaps it requires authentication? Maybe try in incognito/private.

Comment: Can not you visualize the page?
Could you show me the image of the error that shows you?
I do not use auth or any login to see content.

Comment: Sure, this is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/ZgkeXY0.png

Comment: Will it have to see the country? https://i.imgur.com/qhL2Qmh.jpg I am from peru

Comment: I will activate the debug and could I review it and send me error image?